# Multiple User Accounts Possible using Ubuntu 14.04 on Chromebook via Crouton

Tags: chromebook

I just got a Chromebook (Toshiba Chromebook 2) and, of course, instantly used crouton to install Ubuntu 14.04.  Unfortunately, the Toshiba is not currently capable of true dual boot or USB boot (to my knowledge, please correct me if you know something!).  Now I want to use multiple user accounts on the Ubuntu side (e.g., so my kid can have a user profile).

But while I can create a user account, I cannot switch to it.  Logging out goes back to Chrome OS.  And trying to switch accounts seemingly does nothing.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem by switching from Crouton to Coreboot.

Here is [a link](https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download/) to John Lewis' coreboot solution using Sea Bios.

Here is [a link](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=coreboot%20chromebook&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) to the googleplus coreboot on Chromebook community.

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl+Alt+F8. If this doesn't work, try this:

1. First, go to your terminal and type:

   ```
   gksudo gedit  ~/.bashrc
   ```
2. Scroll down to the bottom, and add a line to the bottom.
3. In that line, type (without the brackets):

   ```
   alias switch='su (name of your kid's profile)'
   ```
4. Save that and go to your terminal and type:

   ```
   . ~/.bashrc
   ```
5. Now go to your system settings and navigate to Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts.
6. Press the plus icon.
7. Type in the name field "switch accounts", and in the command field "switch".
8. Click to the far right of the field where it says "switch accounts" and press Ctrl+Shift+/.
9. Now whenever you press that you should switch accounts to your kid's account.

You can also do the same on your kid's account to switch back to your profile.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately, that does not work. I noticed that when I create the kid profile, it creates the `/home/kidname` folder and populates it only with six hidden files (taken from `/etc/skel'):  .Xauthority; .bash_logout; .bashrc; .profile; and .xscreensaver. I have tried creating a new user two ways: (1) `sudo adduser kidname`; and (2) in `System Settings>User Accounts>plus button`. In both instances, a `kidname` folder is created in '/home/`, but I cannot switch to it. Also, I want to make clear that this is on a **Chromebook** running Ubuntu 14.04 using **crouton**.

Comment: Also, not sure this is relevant, but in `System Settings>User Accounts`, the user that is not selected changes from a little person silhouette to a little devil silhouette. And I can't make any changes (the lock won't unlock). To do so, I need to open `System Settings` using `gksu`.

Comment: @MBWD, So both solutions don't work? Its unlikely, but it could be that the problem comes from having both OSs running at the same time. Try running `gksudo adduser testname`

Comment: @MBWD Try running what I said before; `gksudo adduser testname`, then run `sudo passwd testname`. You will be prompted to enter your password, then after that, enter the new password for the new account "testname". Unfortunately you have to have at least one character in your password. After you have done all this, try switching accounts by going to your menu which has all the functions; shutdown, log off, switch users, and try to switch accounts from there. If if comes up with a black screen with a blinking underscore, wait a bit, and if it doesn't load after 20 seconds, press Ctrl+Alt+F7.

Comment: Thanks @ShpeeLord -- but no go.  I can add the user and create a password.   But when I go to the system menu (upper right corner in Ubuntu) and try to switch accounts, I get the same result: nothing.

Comment: @MBWD, this is pretty puzzling. Well for me at least! One more thing, and I know you did this before, but try running:
`gksudo adduser test`
then
`sudo passwd test`
then press Ctrl+Alt+F8, and if that doesn't work... I have no idea. Sorry.

Comment: Darn!  Nothing again (other than adding the user):  still can't switch. Here is some of the code that resulted after `gksudo adduser test`:                                                                                                                                             `Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Adding user `test' ...
Adding new group `test' (1002) ...
Adding new user `test' (1002) with group `test' ...
Creating home directory '/home/test' ...
Copying files from '/etc/skel' ...
Try again? [y/N] Changing the user information for test`
.............

Comment: `Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
 Full Name []:  Room Number []:  Work Phone []:  Home Phone []: Other []: Is the information correct? [Y/n] passwd: password unchanged
Use of uninitialized value $answer in chop at /usr/sbin/adduser line 563.
Use of uninitialized value $answer in pattern match (m//) at /usr/sbin/adduser line 564.
Use of uninitialized value $answer in chop at /usr/sbin/adduser line 589.
Use of uninitialized value $answer in pattern match (m//) at /usr/sbin/adduser line 590.`

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new user on a Chromebook running crouton:

This may be done as:

Add a new user, directory, and shell:

```
sudo useradd -m -d /home/newusername -s /bin/bash newusername
```

Set a password:

```
sudo passwd newusername
```

Unlock the user

```
sudo usermod -U newusername
```

switch to the new user

```
su newusername
```

Edit `/etc/sudoer`
Comment out the line `newusername ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` with a hash `#`
This is to prevent the new user from having `sudo` privileges.

You could also set privileges on each new users home directory to prevent other users from viewing the contents.

Hope this helps :-)